# ember-cordova - Invalid or unexpected token on __dirname

Tags: node.js, cordova, ember.js, phonegap

I'm trying to build Android app using my Ember frontend and Cordova.

1. I've configured project as described in `ember-cordova` docs (changed `rootURL` and `locationType`),
2. I installed `ember-cordova` via `ember install ember-cordova`,
3. Changed app name and widget id in `cordova/config.xml`,
4. Added required platform - `ember cdv:platform add android`,
5. And I'm trying to build first version of my app using `ember cdv:build --platform=android --environment=production`.

Unfortunatelly, build fails with error:

```
EmberCordovaError: Invalid or unexpected token


Stack Trace and Error Report: /tmp/error.dump.0bfefb855ac286c6b6600c600e92d126.log
```

It happens both on Ubuntu 21.10 and macOS Monterey. I'm using `node v12.22.7` installed via node version manager (tried using node from apt packages on Ubuntu, but it didn't help), `ember-cordova v1.0.9`, and `ember v3.12.1`.

Full error log:

```
=================================================================================

ENV Summary:

  TIME: Fri Dec 03 2021 12:37:28 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
  TITLE: ember
  ARGV:
  - /home/tomasz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.7/bin/node
  - /home/tomasz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.7/bin/ember
  - cdv:build
  - --platform=android
  - --environment=production
  EXEC_PATH: /home/tomasz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.7/bin/node
  TMPDIR: /tmp
  SHELL: /bin/bash
  PATH:
  - /home/tomasz/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/bin
  - /home/tomasz/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3@global/bin
  - /home/tomasz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/bin
  - /home/tomasz/.rvm/bin
  - /home/tomasz/.local/bin
  - /home/tomasz/bin
  - /home/tomasz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.7/bin
  - /home/tomasz/.local/bin
  - /home/tomasz/bin
  - /usr/local/sbin
  - /usr/local/bin
  - /usr/sbin
  - /usr/bin
  - /sbin
  - /bin
  - /usr/games
  - /usr/local/games
  - /snap/bin
  - /home/tomasz/.rvm/bin
  PLATFORM: linux x64
  FREEMEM: 18971971584
  TOTALMEM: 33553645568
  UPTIME: 4862
  LOADAVG: 6.15,4.98,3.74
  CPUS:
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4670 CPU @ 3.40GHz - 3505
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4670 CPU @ 3.40GHz - 3565
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4670 CPU @ 3.40GHz - 3800
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4670 CPU @ 3.40GHz - 3800
  ENDIANNESS: LE
  VERSIONS:
  - ares: 1.17.2
  - brotli: 1.0.9
  - cldr: 37.0
  - http_parser: 2.9.4
  - icu: 67.1
  - llhttp: 2.1.4
  - modules: 72
  - napi: 8
  - nghttp2: 1.41.0
  - node: 12.22.7
  - openssl: 1.1.1l
  - tz: 2019c
  - unicode: 13.0
  - uv: 1.40.0
  - v8: 7.8.279.23-node.56
  - zlib: 1.2.11

ERROR Summary:

  - broccoliBuilderErrorStack: [undefined]
  - code: [undefined]
  - codeFrame: [undefined]
  - errorMessage: EmberCordovaError: Invalid or unexpected token
  - errorType: [undefined]
  - location:
    - column: [undefined]
    - file: [undefined]
    - line: [undefined]
  - message: EmberCordovaError: Invalid or unexpected token
  - name: EmberCordovaError
  - nodeAnnotation: [undefined]
  - nodeName: [undefined]
  - originalErrorMessage: [undefined]
  - stack: (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { #!/usr/bin/env node
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:88:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:261:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:309:10)
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Api.getPlatformInfo (/home/tomasz/Projects/app-ember/ember-cordova/cordova/platforms/android/cordova/Api.js:174:22)
    at /home/tomasz/Projects/app-ember/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:53:67
    at Array.map (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at /home/tomasz/Projects/app-ember/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:51:43
    at _fulfilled (/home/tomasz/Projects/app-ember/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at /home/tomasz/Projects/app-ember/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/tomasz/Projects/app-ember/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /home/tomasz/Projects/app-ember/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/home/tomasz/Projects/app-ember/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)


=================================================================================
```

What could be a reason of such a failure?